# How to strip android.Log.d?

Tags: android, ant, proguard, dex

## General assumptions

So I found a lot about using proguard to strip log statements from code. Basically all say -assumenosideeffects together with using the ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt config would do the trick. My understanding was to get bytecode that is equal to doing some

```
if(Consts.DEBUG) Log.d("","");
```

aka I assumed to get the call to doSomeExpensiveStuff() eliminated from my apk:

```
android.util.Log.d("Hello","World"+(new Foo().doSomeExpensiveStuff()));
```

## My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class Slooow {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // being slow
            try {
               Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return "bla";
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("tag", "onCreate: " + (new Slooow().toString()));
    }
}
```

proguard-project.txt:

```
-repackageclasses ''
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontobfuscate
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { public * ; }
```

## Decompiled dex file

```
.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.limit registers 5
; this: v3 (Lcom/example/test/MainActivity;)
; parameter[0] : v4 (Landroid/os/Bundle;)
.line 18
    invoke-super    {v3,v4},android/app/Activity/onCreate   ; onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.line 19
    const/high16    v0,32515
    invoke-virtual  {v3,v0},com/example/test/MainActivity/setContentView    ; setContentView(I)V
.line 20
    new-instance    v0,java/lang/StringBuilder
    const-string    v1,"onCreate: "
    invoke-direct   {v0,v1},java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>  ; <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    new-instance    v1,com/example/test/MainActivity$Slooow
    const/4 v2,0
    invoke-direct   {v1,v2},com/example/test/MainActivity$Slooow/<init> ; <init>(B)V
    invoke-virtual  {v1},com/example/test/MainActivity$Slooow/toString  ; toString()Ljava/lang/String;
    move-result-object  v1
    invoke-virtual  {v0,v1},java/lang/StringBuilder/append  ; append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
.line 21
    return-void 
.end method
```

## Problem

Now if I deploy this to my device, I don't get any log output but still the 5s sleep (or any other delay or crash from code that shouldn't bother my users).
What am I doing wrong?

## Further investigations

```
Log.d("t", "h" + "w");                           // would get stripped just fine.
if(DEBUG)
  Log.d("t", "h: " + (new Slooow().toString())); // would get optimized away, too.
Log.d("t", "h" + bundle.toString());             // has just the same problem as described above.
```

Comment: faced same problem application crashed when i used the apk which is obfuscated by `ant release` command

Comment: @juned this question doesn't have anything to do with an application crash ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like proguard still considers the creation of the new `Slooow` instance to be/have a side effect. At the bytecode level at which proguard works, there is essentially no difference between:

```
Log.d("tag", "onCreate: " + (new Slooow().toString()));
```

and

```
String temp = new Sloooow().toString();
Log.d("tag", "onCreate: " + temp);
```

So proguard sees the `Log.d`, and strips that out, but it's not stripping out the creation of the new `Sloooow` instance, because it hasn't been told that that has no side effects.

I can't think of any good way to generically strip out the creation of Sloooow(), without specifically telling proguard that it has no side effect. (I don't know offhand if that is even possible for a constructor)

Comment: Sounds plausible. I need some sleep and hope for a slightly more promising answer that actually securely solves my problem but somehow I feel like there is little to add, given my proguard-centric question :)

Comment: That's correct. ProGuard doesn't know that the constructor and the toString method don't have side-effects. Explicitly telling ProGuard might have undesirable effects, since it would (currently) apply to all toString() implementations, for instance. And the StringBuilder methods do have side-effects, even though they're only internal. Possible solution: if you can create your own logging method that contains all the extra code, you can specify -assumenosideeffects on it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the answer, I believe that having `final static boolean DEBUG = false` will result in `if(D) { Log.d(...) }` being completely stripped by the compiler

Comment: Thank you Alex for the quick reply. Unfortunately this "overhead" is not desired although it is the only workaround apart from ugly sed-scripting that I could come up with for now.
(Also I want to understand, why proguard cares at all if I print a constant String or start a virtual box inside a Log(,) call when it is explicitly told to consider it not to have any side-effects.)

Comment: Ah, I thought you just wanted to strip the logcat output, sorry